# Is URL Authorization enough secure in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, security, url, authorization

I have categorized my pages in different folders based on some roles and using URL authorization , For example I use the following code in web.config for limiting access to that administrative stuff :

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Admin" />
      <allow roles="SuperAdmin" />
      <deny roles="Member" />
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

My question is : Is that enough secure ? 
Or I need to do some other things like : in every events which user want to do administrative stuff  , I should check If they are in appropriate role ?

**Edit:**
I use "Forms Authentication Provider" and "ASP.NET Membership Provider" for authenticating users and Membership , And as far as i know it's secure

Comment: Is that secure enough is a very relative question. I am not a asp.net programmer, but have worked in security before and I am pretty sure some security expert will find a whole in your application. For starters, what is your authentication framework. (Ideally should be implemented as a filter, using some technique like LDAP binding). Is the user role populated as part of your authentication mechanism?

Comment: If you have a decent authentication framework ( If username and password authentication, then you should worry about ssl and such to avoid man in the middle attack) and that the role cannot be injected by a client request, you should be fine. (Of course if this is a commercial application, you need to implement something like Oauth )

Comment: @Doc: I user default ASP.NET Form Authentication Provider and ASP.NET Mebership Provider

Comment: You should be fine.(based on the information you provided. ) Unless you need a fine grained control, your idea of not adding any authorization logic in code is very good.

Comment: We need to destinguish between authentication and authorization. Authentication is done once for each page request and checks, if the user really is the one she pretends. Authorization checks, if the (authenticated) user is allowed to take the information/the action requested. Authorization is done for each information /action and therefore potentially happens several times in the page livecycle. While authentication runs pretty much out of the box, you will have to decide individually, where and when to use authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does only verify, no user is getting any page delivered, which she is not authorized for. Since you are doing a lot of business stuff in your business layer, you want to check the autorization there also.

Most the time you cant avoid having to check several time *inside* the page also, since the pages often deliver different content, depending if a low right user or a high right user requests them.

In general you will have to decide on your own for every single information you are giving away - is it ok or not? If it not in general a public information: think about, how could you restrict it effectively? The authorization scheme based on the ASP.NET membership classes is a good base to do so.